# Pinterest authentication fails: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "pinterestsdk.v1://oauth

Tags: ios, swift, rest, oauth-2.0, pinterest

I'm trying to implement authentication between my Swift app and Pinterest. I can get the app to open pinterest authentication page in Safari but the after I enter my Pinterest username/password and press OKAY, the app throws the following error message:

CODE:

```
PDKClient.configureSharedInstanceWithAppId("************")//replaced appid with **** 

let permission = [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions]


PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticateWithPermissions(permission, fromViewController: self, withSuccess: { (pdk :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in print("success PDKResponseObject: \(pdk)")
}) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
    print("errori tuli: error NSError: \(err)")
}
```

ERROR:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "pinterestsdk.v1://oauth/?app_name=MyApp&permissions=read_public&client_id=4853625080298613350" - error: "(null)"
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. ALL HELP APPRECIATED!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am stuck right where you are/were

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here at Gibhub. In short, I was editing the wring plist.info. https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk/issues/117#issuecomment-244440823